# Can SharePoint 2013 Auto-change the default view of a document library?

Tags: view, default

I want to embed the "view" of a document library on a page. Current default view is set to May 2016 (current month). I want document library to auto-update this view to "June 2016" next month. Is it possible? How?

The benefit is that I don't have to log in and edit the page for 'view' every month.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view based on a calculated column or using [Today]. So, if you create a calculated column that stores the month and year extracted from the document library, you can create a view that filters the items based on the calculated field!

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a developer on staff, this can be done with code.  Would advise creating a timer job to run once a month with the update code.

This should put you on the right track:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-view-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

Comment: Not a developer; company does not have interest to train me to be one either. But the link you sent me, where can I get layman's info to start learning developing ..?